# .Net application uses too much memory viewing a million data (Mysql, Datagridview)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

My C#.net application uses over 500MB memory viewing 1 million data. I'm using Mysql(simple select * from table) and a Datagridview

Comment: Just for curiosity. How much time is needed to view 1 million data?

Comment: About 5-10 seconds (ID, Name, Email, Phone, Address)

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. How much time is needed to you (or your user) to view that data?. Why do you load all this info? There is a reason to not use a more meaningful query using a where statement to limit the resultset returned?

Comment: If I limit the returned data what'll the right number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all rows of the table with one million data items is kept in memory then 500 MB can be reached easily reached (assuming something about 520 Bytes per row).

In order to reduce the memory usage you can handle this by using the `VirtualMode` of a `DataGridView`. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx for a start.

Combined with paging in MSSQL queries you can get a finer control about what portions of data are kept in memory.

This will add complexity but will reduce the memory consumption.